# NEWID() SQL Server using procedures

Tags: sql-server, northwind

I use NORTHWIND database and I have to use procedure which inserts new value into dbo.Customers.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_InsertCustomer') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC dbo.usp_InsertCustomer;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_InsertCustomer
    @CompanyName AS nvarchar(40), 
    @ContactName AS nvarchar(30) = NULL,
    @ContactTitle AS nvarchar(30) = NULL,
    @Address AS nvarchar(60) = NULL,
    @City AS nvarchar(15) = NULL,
    @Region AS nvarchar(15) = NULL,
    @PostalCode AS nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @Country AS nvarchar(15) = NULL,
    @Phone AS nvarchar(24) = NULL,
    @Fax AS nvarchar(24) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Customers(CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle,
        Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @CompanyName, @ContactName, @ContactTitle, @Address, @City,
         @Region, @PostalCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax);
END
GO
```

And when I tried to use this procedure

```
EXEC dbo.usp_InsertCustomer @CompanyName = N'MyCompany'
```

I get

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the Northwind DB that is around the internet, CustomerID is expect a value of nchar(5), and NEWID() will return a uniqueidentifier. Try changing this, so you can insert the correct value into CustomerID.

EDIT:

This is a VERY BAD way to generate an automatic ID, but for your situation, you can do something like this:

```
(SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(CustomerID, '0'))) + 1 FROM dbo.Customers)
```

This is assuming that all the CustomerIDs values are integer on the table.

The best way to go is what Sean Lange mentioned on the comments: add the IDENTITY property to the CustomerID column (for this, you need to change the data type to INT), and let SQL SERVER take care of the auto increment.

Comment: Oh, I thought NEWID() creates ID connected in some way with key in Customers or any table. So how can I automatically create new ID?

Comment: For an nvarchar column you can't create a new value for the ID automatically. You would need to use an identity for that sort of thing.

Comment: This is a very bad bad BAD practice, but since you are using the NORTHWIND DB, you can get the CustomerID, convert it to INTEGER, assuming that by rule, all the records that you are going to insert are integer, and get the MAX, and add 1. Basically simulating what IDENTITY does. Again, BAD BAD idea, but it can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CustomerID uniqueidentifier
SET @CustomerID = NEWID()
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(@CustomerID AS NVARCHAR(36)),0,5)
```

This helped.

Comment: There is a good possibility that you can get a duplicate value using this method, hence creating a primary key violation.